# Visual Studio Installer - Unable to acquire updated Visual Studio Installer

Tags: visual-studio

I have a problem with installing Visual Studio 2022 from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/fr/downloads/

I got this error when I try to run VisualStudioSetup.exe .This is my first attempt

> Unable to acquire updated Visual Studio Installer. This problem occurs when the installer on your machine is the same or lower than the version to update. If this is your first attempt, we recommend that you Continue to install the Visual Studio update.
> [Continue] [Cancel]

When I click continue and this error appear

> Unable to launch the installer. Error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I 've try to unistall and ran setup.exe again but it didn't work..